# Incorrected image after cvResize

Tags: c++, image, opencv

In my work I use OpenCV 2.4.6 for image resizing by cvResize().
I noted that function carried out a transformation for some image resolutions incorrect. For example,

The image 782x716:  [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51370580/1_src_782_716.jpg)

After transformation for 640x480 I get an incorrect image:
[image]

The image 780x716: [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51370580/2_src_780_716.jpg)
For it I get a normal image 640x480:
[image]

My codes:

> void ScaleBufOpenCV(BYTE *in, BYTE *out, int inX, int inY, int outX, int outY,  int   nResizeNumber )
>   {

```
IplImage Src_img;
cvInitImageHeader( &Src_img, cvSize(inX, inY), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
cvSetData( &Src_img, (char*)in, inX*3 );

IplImage Dst_img;
cvInitImageHeader( &Dst_img, cvSize(outX, outY), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
cvSetData( &Dst_img, (char*)out, outX*3 );

cvResize (&Src_img, &Dst_img, nResizeNumber);
cvSaveImage("d:\\1.jpg", &Dst_img);
```

}

Where,

- in - input buffer for source image
- out - output buffer for destination image
- inX, inY - size of input image
- outX, outY - size of output image, always it's equal 640x480
- nResizeNumber - interpolation method, always it's equal 1

Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use `cv::Mat()` instead ?

Comment: I would like to use C-functions, because have a big legacy project

Answer (score 0):

`IplImage` is a part of the C interface for OpenCV, I recommend using `Mat` as suggested (C++ structure). Then you can easily resize your image with `cv::resize(mat_to_resize, mat_resized, Size(640,480), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);`

Comment: I cannot make it. C-interface of  opencv  is used in the big legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, change

```
cvSetData( &Src_img, (char*)in, inX*3 );
```

on

```
Src_img.imageData = (char*)in;
```

works well!